# How to customize the "Clear" checkbox for a models.ImageField in django Admin page?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-models, django-modeladmin

i have a Model for a user profile in my django app that has a models.ImageField and i have an ModelAdmin for it
when a user uploads an image , in the admin page , when i go in that user's Customize page , in the ImageField section , there is the url of uploaded image and a checkbox named "Clear" and a button for updating the image. how can i change the text of that checkbox ? for example i want it to have the text "Delete" instead of "Clear"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like "Clear" is hardcode.

So either you create a custom widget simply like that:

```
class MyClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    clear_checkbox_label = ugettext_lazy('Delete')
```

And assign it to your form field like that

```
MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfile=ImageField(widget=MyClearableFileInput)
```

Or add overwrite it in your admin

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ImageField: {'widget': MyClearableFileInput},
    }
```

Or you use the translation mechanisms to translate Clear into Delete. Django translation is described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) pretty well.

I personally, just think that it is quite some overhead for your problem, unless you are using translations anyway. I would clearly recommend the custom widget - the addtional code is really minimal.

Comment: i just want to edit these :
class MyModel(models.Model)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
not add or edit anything else like "class MyClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput)"
What should i do ?

Comment: as I wrote, your second option is translation. Although it would help, if you explained in more detail, why you can't go for the other approach. As I said, "Clear" is hardcoded. No easy way around it!

Comment: how can i change the translation of 'clear' in django translation mechanism ?

Comment: I just updated my answer. If you are still hesitant to create your custom widget, please share some more details of your concerns.

Comment: how can i assign class MyClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput) in to my form field ?

Comment: it's a models.ImageField and it has no argument 'widget'